# JSON jQuery display to table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, pdo

How do I render JSON data in a table . I tried with below code :

**HTML** :

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>

      <th>Name</th>

      <th>Password</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>  
  <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
</table>

<button id="get">Get</button> 

<script src="script/ajax.googleapis.com_ajax_libs_jquery_1.10.1_jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<!--<script src="script/myScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
<script src="script/json_array.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Script-jQuery**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 done();

});


function done() {
      setTimeout( function() { 
      updates(); 
      done();
      }, 200);
}

function updates() {
     $.getJSON("fetch.php", function(data) {
       $.each(data, function (index, item) {
     var eachrow = "<tr>"
                 + "<td>" + item[1] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item[2] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item[3] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item[4] + "</td>"
                 + "</tr>";
     $('#tbody').append(eachrow);
});
 });
}
```

**PHP script**

```
<?php
include "./pdoConn.php";
$output = array();
$query = "select * from wishers";
$stmt = $pdo->query($query);
$stmt->execute();
$name = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($name);
?>
```

**output of json** :

```
    [
      {"id":"1","name":"Tom","password":"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"},
      {"id":"2","name":"Jerry","password":"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"},  
      {"id":"3","name":"Kate","password":"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"},  
      {"id":"4","name":"Joan","password":"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"},
      {"id":"5","name":"Cyril","password":"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"},
      {"id":"8","name":"Ama","password":"ama"},      
      {"id":"7","name":"Akusika","password":"mummy"},
      {"id":"9","name":"Abetiafa","password":"joko"}
    ]
```

Comment: You can try: https://json2html.herokuapp.com/
I developed this app(open-sourced). The JSON 2 HTML parser is written in Python. Try it, code at https://github.com/softvar/json2html-flask

Answer (score 0):

When working with tables and AJAX, I would recommend the jQuery Datatables plugin.  It does a lot of the work for you and there are plenty of packages if you're using a framework like Laravel

http://www.datatables.net

Answer (score 0):

Don't use item[1] use item[id], this is json, not just an array, you can even use item.id.

See json datas as objects (here an array of object), and this object has property with a name, not a number (unless you set it as a name ^^)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
var eachrow = "<tr>"
             + "<td>" + item[index].id + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + item[index].name + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + item[index].password + "</td>"
             + "</tr>";
```

Because you have an array of objects, you have to access the element using `index`, then you access its properties.